# Import CSV timestamp into MySQL acceptable format while using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I have a CSV file with the timestamp in the following format

```
 timestamp,             day_chan2, day_chan3
01/02/2014 00:00,             9,    2
01/02/2014 00:00,            16,    5
```

I am trying to import it into a MySQL database using LOAD DATA INFILE

```
$query_name = "LOAD DATA INFILE ' "
                                . $file_path . 
                                "' INTO TABLE '"
                                . $this->table_name . 
                                 " ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\,' 
                                 LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
                                 IGNORE 1 LINES 
                                 (`time_stamp`,`day_chan2`,`day_chan3`)";
```

My problem is the following: how do I convert the timestamp into a format acceptable to my MySQL while importing it into the database?

I am clueless now on how to change the timestamp into a proper timestamp which I can use to query later.

Comment: you wont be able to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` as you need to run a conversiton on the date field, you will have to loop thought it line by line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried this, but you might be able to do something like:

```
$query_name = "LOAD DATA INFILE ' "
                                . $file_path . 
                                "' INTO TABLE '"
                                . $this->table_name . 
                                 " ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\,' 
                                 LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
                                 IGNORE 1 LINES 
                                 (@mytimestamp,`day_chan2`,`day_chan3`)
                                 SET time_stamp=STR_TO_DATE(@mytimestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i');"
```

There are examples of this in the MySQL documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I'm actually really curious to find out if it works  :)

Comment: you can do that? neat !

Comment: @Dagon I don't actually know.  But that's what it seems like in the documentation  :)  If it doesn't work exactly as above, it might work similarly.

Comment: i never post answers i haven't actully tested.

Comment: I'd [reformat the dates in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) before posting to mysql... Please see my answer for sample code

Comment: @Dagon It will end up edited to show something functional.  Or I'll just remove it.  It seemed like a step in the right direction.

Comment: @hd1 my problem is that I have more than a million lines to edit so i think reformat will slow it down.

Comment: @Bazinga777 See my edit... a million records at once is not a problem -- we do a 3 million record insert daily into mysql in about 15 minutes.

Comment: will have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i was working on something else. Will update what happens after i try it out

Comment: @CullyLarson, I am a little confused on whether I should create the column before dumping it into the database or will it create one by itself.

Comment: @Bazinga777 The table itself should be created before using `LOAD DATA`.  `LOAD DATA` will not do anything like `ALTER TABLE` to create columns.

Comment: Thanks i did a little more research and found out that it is actually possible to do this, gonna implement it now

Comment: @Bazinga777 Did it work the way it's shown in my answer?  I'm just curious if I need to change anything in the answer, in case someone else comes along with the same problem; I don't want there to be a bug  :)

Comment: No, it didn't work completely but I seperated it into two different queries meaning i first dump into db and then create a column and copy it into the new column

Comment: @Bazinga777 What went wrong with just using the initial query?

Comment: There were no errors thrown on the screen but i got a column with all 0s in them,

Comment: Perhaps `STR_TO_DATE` couldn't handle the timestamp correctly?

Comment: Could be so, ill give it a try again later because it could cut down a few lines of code

Comment: @Bazinga777 You could test it by just running something like this in the command line:  `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('a manually entered timestamp from your file', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i');`  If it returns 0, you found your problem  :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQLs [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) is probably the best way to do this, given your comment, see below...

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ". $this->table_name . "(`time_stamp`,`day_chan2`,`day_chan3`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(?, 'd/m/y H:M'),?,?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
for ($fields in $data) {
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $fields[0]);
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $fields[1]);
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $fields[2]);
   if (!$stmt->execute()) {
      echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
   }
}
```

Good luck and leave a comment if you need further help.